# add_action.. will work if function is empty?

Tags: actions

My Example:

```
function example() {
  if ($checked) echo 'true';
 }
add_action('wp_head', 'example');
```

now, if not `$checked`, will wordpress do an empty `add_action` or will avoid it?
if do, how I can just add action if `$checked` is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will run, but nothing will happen. There is a small overhead, but you shouldn't worry about it, the possible savings are minimal.

Depending on when you have $checked available, you could also do

```
function example() {
    echo 'true';
}
if ($checked) add_action('wp_head', 'example');
```

Comment: Thanks, will I need to Declare `$checked` 2 times? one inside function and second outside it?

Comment: No, just outside. If add_action is only executed if($checked), the function will never run unless $checked equals to true. Whether you do it inside or outside the function depends mostly on whether you can determine the value of $checked at template loading time where you don't know which post is requested. If you check it inside example(), get_the_ID() etc will work correctly.